# Your application is missing a Procfile

Tags: procfile

I had such problem when try to deploy my app on Heroku:

> Warning: Your application is missing a Procfile. This file tells Heroku how to run your application.

and

> remote: -----> Installing python-2.7.13

despite the fact I use 3.5.2 python version in my virtualenv.

I had already checked that Procfile is in the root directory, doen't have .txt extension and have been commited. 
How can I fix it? Help, please

Comment: and you respected the exact spelling? can you show a listing of the root of your repo?

Comment: @njzk2
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5ZKL7jCSK_yNnpPeFBqbFFCT1k/view?usp=sharing